# Error attempt to concatenate Instance with string after passing in strings

Tags: lua, webhooks, roblox, httpservice

So I am trying to make a game where in `StarterCharacterScripts` in a local script upon touching a part called `WinPad` for it to fire an event, which send a message in chat, and send a `PostAsync()` to a Discord webhook. However, upon firing the event it gives the error `attempt to concatenate Instance with string` even though all passed in arguments are strings. Here is the event firer in LocalScript:

```
        local name = tP:FindFirstChild("TowerName")
        local diff = tP:FindFirstChild("Difficulty")
        local diffid = tP:FindFirstChild("DifficultyId")
        local diffcolor = tP:FindFirstChild("DiffColor3")
        game.ReplicatedStorage.WinEvent:FireServer(game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name, name.Value, diff.Value, diffid.Value, diffcolor.Value)
```

Here is the `OnServerEvent:Connect()` script:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.WinEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr, towername, towerdiff, towerdiffid, color)
    local HookData = {
            ['content'] = "**"..plr.."** has beaten **"..tostring(towername).." [<:"..tostring(towerdiff)..":"..tostring(towerdiffid)..">]**."
    }
    HookData = http:JSONEncode(HookData)
    http:PostAsync(url, HookData)
    plr.Parent:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-764, 12.5, -54.5))
    createSystemMessage:FireAllClients((plr.." has beaten "..towername.."."), color, Enum.Font.SourceSansBold, Enum.FontSize.Size14)
end)
```

Also, `tP` is the part that is touched by the `LocalPlayer.Character.Humanoid`

Comment: Also, using `WaitForChild()` in the LocalScript does not work.

Comment: You said all are strings but you use `plr` as a table `plr.Parent:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-764, 12.5, -54.5))` and aslo try to concat it in your `HookData['content']` string.

Comment: I added `local player = plr` and change `plr.Parent:MoveTo()` to `player:MoveTo()` and it returns the same error.

Comment: if `plr` is a player table you need to change `['content'] = "**"..plr.."**` to something that gets the name.

Comment: in the LocalScript it already calls the LocalPlayer's Name attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a [RemoteEvents' OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/RemoteEvent/OnServerEvent) signal, the first parameter is always the [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) that used the FireServer function, and that is provided automatically by the engine. Your function signature should look like this :

```
function(player, plrname, towername, towerdiff, towerdiffid, color)
```

But, there's no need to provide the player name, because you could get that from `player.Name`. So to fix your problem and clean up your code, I would recommend this in your LocalScript :

```
local winevent = game.ReplicatedStorage.WinEvent

local name = tP.TowerName.Value
local diff = tP.Difficulty.Value
local diffid = tP.DifficultyId.Value
local diffcolor = tP.DiffColor3.Value

winevent:FireServer(name, diff, diffid, diffcolor)
```

And this in your server Script :

```
local winEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.WinEvent
winEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, towername, towerdiff, towerdiffid, color)
    -- format some messages
    local message = "%s has beaten %s."
    local hookMessage = string.format(message,
        "**" .. player.Name .. "**",
        string.format("**%s [<:%s:%s>]**", towername, towerdiff, towerdiffid))
    local playerMessage = string.format(message, player.Name, towername)

    -- fire some data to some server
    local HookData = {
            ['content'] = hookMessage,
    }
    HookData = http:JSONEncode(HookData)
    http:PostAsync(url, HookData)

    -- move the player's character somewhere
    player.Character:MoveTo(Vector3.new(-764, 12.5, -54.5))

    -- alert everyone that stuff has happened
    createSystemMessage:FireAllClients(playerMessage, color, Enum.Font.SourceSansBold, Enum.FontSize.Size14)
end)
```

Comment: Also, the passing in of the `DiffColor3` Color3 value failed, so I simply made an If statement checking what the difficulty passed in was equal to and setting the Color3 from stored values.